# How to make indexed words clickable in the text?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, imakeidx

I want to make the indexed words into hyperlinks to the entries in the "Index" (something similar to the `glossaries` package).
I'm using `xindy` on `TL2012` and here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Lorem\index{Alpha} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\index{alpha}
adipiscing elit. Proin ullamcorper\index{gnat} quam magna, quis
convallis\index{gnus!good} sapien. Donecat ligula vel dolor
varius\index{bites!vegetable} lobortis id ut orci\index{gnat!size
of}. Maecenas commodo fringilla elit\index{Alphabet}, et pellentesque
purus ornare vitae.  Aenean non metus ipsum. Lorem\index{gnat!anatomy}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing\index{alphas} elit. Ut
mauris lorem, accumsan a sagittis ut, rutrum fringilla arcu. Cras
ullamcorper faucibus\index{alpha bet} quam id molestie.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the indexed words do not necessarily appear in the text at all (for example there can be a `fox` in the text and an `\index{animals}` next to it). Therefore I'm not sure whether I understand your question right.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

Lorem\index{Alpha@\hypertarget{Alpha.ind}{}Alpha}\href{\#Alpha.ind}{Alpha}
ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
\index{alpha@\hypertarget{alpha.ind}{}alpha}\href{\#alpha.ind}{alpha}
adipiscing elit. Proin ullamcorper 
\index{gnat@\hypertarget{gnat.ind}{}gnat}\href{\#gnat.ind}{gnat} quam magna, quis
convallis
\index{gnus!good@\hypertarget{gnusgood.ind}{}good}\href{\#gnusgood.ind}{good} quam magna, ...

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Does this accomplish what you intended? (This works without `xindy`, but with it there can be [problems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82227/6865).)

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Just one more thing: Why do I get errors when redefining the `\index` command as below?     ‎\let\oldindex\index‎
    ‎\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{‎‎  
    \oldindex{#1‎@\hypertarget{#1‎‎.‎ind}{}#1}\href{\##1‎.‎ind}{#1}‎‎‎}‎‎

Comment: You need to `\protect` `\hypertarget`, otherwise it will break: `\let\oldindex\index   
\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\oldindex{#1@\protect\hypertarget{#1.ind}{}#1}\href{\##1.ind}{#1}}`. This redefinition is practical, but it does not work for index entries with subentries, e.g.`\index{gnus!good}`. Either use `\oldindex{gnus!good@\hypertarget{gnusgood.ind}{}good}\href{\#gnusgood.ind}{good}` or feel free to ask a follow-up-question about how to achieve that.

Comment: thanks again, but if I use the `\protect`, the link to the entry in the Index doesn't work!

Comment: That's a pity. Without `xindy` this worked for me, and at the moment I have no idea how to fix it. Because neither index entries with subentries could be used this way, imho it would be appropriate to ask a follow up question "Why does `\let\oldindex...` not work?".

Comment: I asked a follow-up question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82227/why-does-let-oldindex-not-work-in-this-code)