# Why does \let\oldindex not work in this code?

Tags: hyperref, indexing, xindy

> This is a follow-up question to: [How to make indexed words clickable
>   in the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82166/how-to-make-indexed-words-clickable-in-the-text)

I'm having two problems with the code given by @Stephen.

1. If I use the following code to redefine the `\index` command, the link to the entry in the Index, will not work with **`xindy`**

   ```
   ‎\let\oldindex\index‎‎
   \renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\oldindex{#1@\protect‎\hypertarget{#1.ind}{}#1}\href{\#‌​#1.‎ind}{#1}}‎
   ```
2. My index entries with subentries (e.g. `\index{foo!bar}`) could not be used this way.

BTW, my document is in Persian which is an RTL language.

**Edit:**
Here is the code which I'm having problem with it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\let\oldindex\index
\renewcommand*{\index}[1]{\oldindex{#1@\protect\hypertarget{#1.ind}{}#1}\href{\#‌​#1.ind}{#1}}

\begin{document}
test \index{test}% problem 1
\index{foo!bar}% problem 2

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Most likely you need to use `\LetLtxMacro`, instead of `\let`.  A detailed description of `\LetLtxMacro` can be found at this question at [closed square root symbol](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29837/4301).

Comment: Please make a MWE with all the code necessary to show how this "doesn't work".

Comment: @egreg: I added a MWE to my post.

Comment: The problem is that `\subsubitem` is written inside the argument of `\hypertarget`. Probably Xindy gets confused by the two `!` it finds in the same entry.

Comment: @egreg: Isn't there a solution to this problem?

Comment: @egreg Care to expand on your comment here as an answer?

Comment: @JosephWright I'd rather not; there are much more problems with this.

Comment: @egreg Should it be closed, then?

Comment: @cfr No; although I know of no solution.

Answer (score 3):

Since no one has been able to provide an answer, here's an alternative approach. Instead of using `makeidx` and `xindy` this uses [`glossaries-extra`](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) and [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls). This means that instead of using `\index` the terms that need indexing must all be defined in a `.bib` file.

For example, the file `entries.bib` contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{test}

@index{foo}

@index{bar,
  name={bar},
  parent={foo}
}
```

The document `test.tex` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record, % using bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load the default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex% use the bookindex style
 ]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en}% sort by this language tag (en = English)
]

\begin{document}
\Gls{test}.\glsadd{bar}

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]

\end{document}
```

The document build is:

```
pdflatex test
bib2gls -g test
pdflatex test
pdflatex test
```

(Replace `pdflatex` with `xelatex` etc as appropriate. The third instance just makes sure that the PDF bookmarks are up-to-date.)

The result is:

[image: Test. Index F foo bar, 1 T test, 1]

The red text indicates a hyperlink.

If you forget the `-g` (`--group`) switch, you won't get the group headings:

[image: Test. Index foo bar, 1 test, 1]

Notes:

- `@index` first identifies the label used to reference the term (analogous to BibTeX  where the label is used in `\cite`). This will also be the text used in the index and by commands like `\gls` unless overridden by the `name` field.
- The label can't contain any special characters, commas or spaces. When used with `inputenc`, the label also can't contain any non-ASCII characters either, but since you're using Persian I'm guessing that you're probably using `fontspec` with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.
- `\gls{`*label*`}` displays the term and creates a hyperlink to the relevant line in the index. `\Gls` converts the first letter to upper case. You can get the plural forms with `\glspl` and `\Glspl`.
- `\glsadd{`*label*`}` just adds the term to the index without producing any text (and therefore no hyperlink).
- You don't need to specify the language in `sort` if it matches the document language. I've used `sort=en` because the document doesn't include any language information.

Here's another example. File `entries.bib` now contains:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@index{bird}

@index{duck,
  name={duck},
  parent={bird}
}

@index{goose,
  name={goose},
  plural={geese},
  parent={bird}
}

@index{wildfowl,
  alias={bird}
}
```

The document `test.tex` contains:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[record, % using bib2gls
 nostyles,% don't load the default styles
 stylemods={bookindex},% load glossary-bookindex.sty
 style=bookindex% use the bookindex style
 ]{glossaries-extra}

\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={entries}, % data in entries.bib
  sort={en}% sort by this language tag
]

\begin{document}
\Glspl{goose} and \glspl{duck}. \Gls{wildfowl} links to `bird' not 
`wildfowl' in the index.

\printunsrtglossary[title=Index]

\end{document}
```

The result is now:

[image: Geese and ducks. Wildfowl links to ‘bird’ not ‘wildfowl’ in the index. Index B bird, 1 goose, 1 duck, 1 W wildfowl, see bird]